# PostGIS - ST_Union after ST_Resize on tiled raster

Tags: postgresql, postgis, raster, geo, gdal

I have a tiled raster image within PostGIS, consisting of 100x100 px tiles.

My objective is to first resize the tiles to just 1px and then merge all together.
For this I tried the following statement:

```
SELECT ST_Union(
         ST_Resize(rast, 1, 1)
       )
  FROM rasterSource
```

Unfortunately I'm getting the following error message:

```
ERROR: rt_raster_from_two_rasters: The two rasters provided do not have the same alignment
```

...so it is an alignment issue. But how do I provide the necessary information after resizing?

Best regards

Comment: How about `SELECT ST_Resize(ST_Union(rast), 1, 1) ...`?

Comment: Then I have a problem with the maximum array size, so this is unfortunately not a solution.

Comment: I'm not certain because I haven't used Rasters before, but looking at the docs briefly, I'd suggest `SELECT ST_Union( (SELECT ST_Resize(rast, 1, 1) FROM rasterSource) );` -- reason being, ST_Union expects a `setof raster`, and assuming that each raster is distinct in `rasterSource`, you should give to the union function all the resized rasters as a set. Disregard this pseudo-answer if your data in `rasterSource` doesn't fit my assumption.